# Viewing and modifiying elements inside Array of Structs in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

Hi Solidity developers out there!
I need your help on a small issue I am facing. i want to modify certain elements of structs in an Array of structs. I created another mapping ( uint => Struct) to search faster and modify. i am using **pragma solidity ^0.8.8; ** by the way.

## Struct:

```
struct Candidate {
    uint candidateId;
    string CandidateName;
    string party;
    uint voteCount;
}
```

## Array and Mapping:

```
Candidate[] public candidates;

//store candidates for faster votes 
mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidatesMap;
```

## Constructor to test on candidates and fill some candidates in the Array of structs:

```
//constructor to hard fill candidates
constructor(){
    addCandidate(1,"candidate1","party1");
    addCandidate(2,"candidate2","party2");
    addCandidate(3,"candidate3","party3");
}
```

## Function to get and return candidate info:

```
//function to get candidate infos
function getCandidateInfo(uint _candidateId) public view returns (uint, 
string memory, string memory) {
    return(
        candidatesMap[_candidateId].candidateId,
        candidatesMap[_candidateId].CandidateName,
        candidatesMap[_candidateId].party
    );
}
```

**Please help me out. I've been looking for couple of days here and there and I couldn't find solution. **

## Screenshot of my codes in Remix:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to change the Pragma solidity version higher and also adding

```
pragma abicoderv2;
```

but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are tring to return `storage` reference inside `public` function. The solution is to copy the storage reference into the `memory` and then return it. Assuming all other parts of your code is correct, this should work:

```
function getCandidateInfo(uint _candidateId) public view returns (uint, 
string memory, string memory) {

    Candidate memory candidate=candidatesMap[_candidateId]
    return(
        candidate.candidateId,
        candidate.CandidateName,
        candidate.party
    );
}
```